# Linux console with multiple video cards

Tags: linux, arch-linux, video

I have an older desktop box with two independent video cards.
When booting, the BIOS chooses one card and produces normal output there.

The system runs a arch linux system. As soon as the kernel starts up it probably detects both cards, is "confused" and produces nothing on the one card and garbage (something like random colorful pixel) on the other card.

The system does **not** run any X-Server. Only plain text mode.

- How do I get a useful output?
- Is there any way to specify which card the kernel should use?

Comment: What model are the two video cards? Are you using the video card's text mode or a framebuffer? (What options are you passing on the kernel command line?)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like linux tries to set up some kind of frame buffer.

[Disabling framebuffer](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/kernel_mode_setting#Disabling_modesetting) by adding `nomodeset` to the kernel command line should work.